# How to create spock-style DSL for dataset description?

Tags: java, groovy, spock

I'd like to have a dataset description in a spock data-driven specs format:

```
'Key'   |    'Value'    |    'Comments'
1       |    'foo'      |    'something'
2       |    'bar'      |    'something else'
```

This has to be transformed to something like 2D array (or whatever is possible to implement).

Any ideas how to implement this data description?

p.s. The biggest problem is linebreak detection, the rest can be implemented by overloading `or` on Object's `metaClass`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `|` operator is left-associative, so a line in that table will be parsed like:

```
('Key' | 'Value') | 'Comments'
```

What you can then do to detect where each row starts and ends is to make `|` opeator return a list with its operands and then for each `|` ask whether the left-hand operand (i.e. `this`) is a list. If it is, then it means it's a continuation of a row; if it's not a list, it means it's a new row.

Here's a full example of a DSL to parse those datasets using a [Category](http://groovy.codehaus.org/gapi/groovy/lang/Category.html) to avoid overriding things on the Object metaclass:

```
@Category(Object)
class DatasetCategory {
    // A static property for holding the results of the DSL.
    static results

    def or(other) {
        if (this instanceof List) {
            // Already in a row. Add the value to the row.
            return this << other
        } else {
            // A new row.
            def row = [this, other]
            results << row
            return row
        }
    }
}

// This is the method that receives a closure with the DSL and returns the 
// parsed result.
def dataset(Closure cl) {
    // Initialize results and execute closure using the DatasetCategory.
    DatasetCategory.results = []
    use (DatasetCategory) { cl() }

    // Convert the 2D results array into a list of objects:
    def table = DatasetCategory.results
    def header = table.head()
    def rows = table.tail()
    rows.collect { row -> 
        [header, row].transpose().collectEntries { it } 
    }
}

// Example usage.
def data = dataset {
    'Key'   |    'Value'    |    'Comments'
    1       |    'foo'      |    'something'
    2       |    'bar'      |    'something else'
}

// Correcness test :)
assert data == [
    [Key: 1, Value: 'foo', Comments: 'something'],
    [Key: 2, Value: 'bar', Comments: 'something else']
]
```

In this example, i parsed the table as a list of maps, but you should be able to do anything you want with the results of the DatasetCategory after the DSL closure has run.